# How can be initialize vector array when 2D array vector is full?

Tags: vector, stl, mfc

I made dynamic vector class..

But the problem show when main function is looping on and on,

my2dArr's row size is increasing when the function is looping

When data is coming on looping, i want to copy new data..

```
  void main()
     {

       int data[450];

     DynamicArray<int> my2dArr(36, 100);
     for(int i = 0;i < 36;++i)
        {
            for(int j = 1;j < 16;++j)
            {


              my2dArr[i][j-1] = data[i];

            }   

        }   

    }
```

// vector class

```
    class DynamicArray
    {
    public:
        DynamicArray(){};

        DynamicArray(int rows, int cols): dArray(rows, vector<T>(cols)){}

        vector<T> & operator[](int i) 
        { 
          return dArray[i];
        }
        const vector<T> & operator[] (int i) const 
        { 
          return dArray[i];
        }
        void resize(int rows, int cols)//resize the two dimentional array .
        {
            dArray.resize(rows);
            for(int i = 0;i < rows;++i) dArray[i].resize(cols);
        }

    void clearCOL()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < dArray.size();i++)
    {
          for(int j = 0;j < dArray[i].size();++j)
          {

            dArray[j].erase();
          }
    }

        }
    private:
        vector<vector<T> > dArray;  
    };
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What's the actual error you're getting? Also please fix your code indentation for it to be more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested for loop should be fine at Initializing your array, but you'd need to put values into the `data` array to use it in initializing.

If you're only initializing the data once you might consider a third constructor overload that takes in an `int[]`, like so:

```
DynamicArray( int rows, int cols, T array[] ): dArray( rows, vector< T >( cols ) )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {

        for( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            dArray[i][j] = array[i * rows + j];
        }
    }
}
```

You'd need to make sure the array was the size you specified. In your example you pass a 450 int array in to initialize a 3,600 int DynamicArray. In you're example you're actually reading illegal data cause you go to the 16th column of each of the 36 rows so you're actually reading 576 elements from a 450 int array. I suppose the array is uninitialized anyway though, so it's all garbage.

Comment: Yeah, no problem.

If that answers your question you should accept the answer by clicking the check-mark icon next to my answer.

If I still haven't answered what you were trying to ask let me know and I will try to clarify.